# Python 3 program works in command line, not IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

This simple program works when entered from a command line, but not in IDLE.

```
#
import msvcrt

while not msvcrt.kbhit():
   print('.', end='')
print("kbhit!")
```

I had hoped this problem would disappear in Python 3.

Some questions:

1. Is there a way to get around this in IDLE?
2. Is there some other Python code editor that does not have this limitation?
3. I am writing a blog on my transition to Python3 and I would like to explain WHY I have to transfer my work from IDLE to a command line. What is the simple, boxtop explanation of this apparent inconsistency, suitable for passing on to readers who don't know Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How* does it not work?

Comment: In IDLE, the program detects and echoes the key pressed, but does not stop and type kbhit! as in:<br> ............................6......................................6...............................6............................

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the previous answer of user3666197 back to 0 and will add a bit more. Idle itself runs in one process.  Unless started with -n, Idle runs your code, whether a statement entered in the Shell at >>> or a whole module in an editor.  The keyboard remains attached to the Idle process and the echoed key hits in '....6..............6...' are from the Idle code, not your code.

Out of curiosity, I started Idle with -n, and the tk mainloop still grabs key events first and your program still runs indefinitely.

[edit] I also ran the test program in the question, saved as tem.py, with the following

```
>>> import subprocess as sb
>>> sb.Popen("python c:/programs/python34/tem.py")
```

This works the same as running the program from the console.  Hitting a key printed 'kbhit!' and closed the window.  This also works when run from a second editor window.

I am thinking of adding this idea to the Idle doc as a general way to run programs, like this one, that interact badly with Idle's run environment.  (This is not the first.) Or perhaps there should be a new Run menu entry. I am not sure what to call it.  Run Batch?  Run in Console?

Adding `input()` at the end of the test program keeps the window open after the key entry.

Adding time.sleep(.5) in the loop causes the '.' prints to be collected in a buffer and not displayed until a key is hit.  The has nothing to do with Idle as the same is true if the program is executed in a console, as with

```
C:\Programs\Python34>python tem.py
```

Comment: What is "the previous answer"? Answers can appear in different orders over time.

Comment: The previous answer of user3666197 (id added in edit).

Answer (score 0):

### This is not related to a python, but a known IDLE issue

You may want to know, that IDLE is a layered application, that uses Tcl/Tk based Tkinter Controller part, that also scans and evaluates keyboard-related events in the **`.mainloop()`** and that simply gets into conflict with your intention to detect **`.kbhit()`**

### A1:

No.

### A2:

Yes, Notepad.exe besides many other editors. If insisted on IDE, **PyScripter** might be such a candidate, as it does not rely on Tcl/Tk Tkinter framework and has many smart options ( internal / external python interpreter, intellisense, object-introspection, help on imported modules' via their respective `.__doc__`-strings and many other )

### A3:

Understanding an un-avoidable collision of two concurrent Controllers ( a `.mainloop()` + `.kbdhit()` )

**Btw**., IDLE's `.mainloop()` won in your demonstrated example :o)

**N.b.**: Where is your blog posted?

Comment: Thanks for your clear (if disappointing) answer. Unfortunately, I was unclear in my second question. I should have said "Is there any other program that both edits AND runs programs and offers IDLE-like debug assistance that does not have this limitation?"

Comment: I could not upvote your answer @user3666197 because I don't have the "reputation" on stackoverflow. My blog is at [link](http://www.zer0sum.net/predicto//predictotop.htm). I will look at PySCripter.

Comment: Will do when my online street cred is a little higher. On my program, undecided on details of the rewrite, not ready to discuss publicly. The accuracy of its daily forecasts is not great -- I treat it with the same attention I pay to the talking heads on cable news business channels -- just another damn fool opinion. Would welcome your opinion on my Python writing style on the code in that blog.